# concatenate multiple results of table-valued function into a single table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Let's assume there is such table in SqlServer 2008 database:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (    
  [TableId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT> NULL, 
  [Data] [xml] NOT NULL 
)
```

and also I have such table-valued function to parse column `Data` in my table:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseTable] (@header XML) 
  RETURNS @parsedTable TABLE (
   [Type] NVARCHAR(50),
   [Value] NVARCHAR(50)  
  )     
 AS BEGIN  
         --parse xml here 
 RETURN  
END
```

Can I concatenate all results of this function for each column of the table?

I need something like this:

```
 SELECT UNION fnParseTable(Data) FROM dbo.Test
```

PS. I know I can do it using cursor, but I want to make sure there are no any easier solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a table valued function, use [XPath to extract these values directly in a SELECT statement](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050803.htm)

```
SELECT 
    Data.query('data(/xpath/to[@your="type"])') AS type,
    Data.query('data(/xpath/to[@your="value"])') AS value
FROM Test
/* JOINs, WHERE HAVING, GROUP BY and/or ORDER BY clauses */
```

`query()` executes an XPath expression, while `data()` extracts a value from the resulting XML node.

**Update**

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE(
    XmlData XML
)

INSERT INTO @testTable (XmlData)
VALUES ('<row><node><key>key11</key><value>value11</value></node><node><key>key12</key><value>value12</value></node></row>')

INSERT INTO @testTable (XmlData)
VALUES ('<row><node><key>key21</key><value>value21</value></node><node><key>key22</key><value>value22</value></node></row>')

INSERT INTO @testTable (XmlData)
VALUES ('<row><node><key>key31</key><value>value31</value></node><node><key>key32</key><value>value32</value></node></row>')

SELECT 
    nref.value('key[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS [key],
    nref.value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS value
FROM @testTable CROSS APPLY XmlData.nodes('//node') AS R(nref)
```

Result

```
key11   value11
key12   value12
key21   value21
key22   value22
key31   value31
key32   value32
```

Comment: SELECT 
 Data.query('/path').value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS type
 FROM Test.


Results of this SELECT are like this:

row1Data1row1Data2row1Data3
row1Data2row2Data2row2Data3
row1Data3row3Data2row3Data3

So, it just concatenates values in strings

Comment: I can you give you a better answer if provide example XML for a row and the output you want.

Comment: This site doesn't allow xml in posts. So, I created google online doc  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UzHz3_qb2klJJvJM9l6IoUAuxpQlm8q8m475_R_zujg/edit?hl=en
And here the result I expect: https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AlLEbQbwDYKNdHNuWXlvUFBMTjR2ZGRBVzdqWmNzTUE&hl=en. (I hope you have google account)

Comment: By the way.... I have completed this task already. I just used CURSOR. But I would be very thankful if you could give me an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Orangepips answer seems the adequate solution for your problem.

But taking the question verbatim: **YES** there is a way to create a suitable aggregate function using CLR in SQL-Server 2005+.

But it is admittedly a bit complicated.

You have to compile the c# code, you find at [Invoking CLR User-Defined Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx).

I succeeded in running that example, but I prefer to use orangepips xpath solutions when suitable, because it is just T-SQL und requires no

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled',1
reconfigure
```

Comment: Thanks. But this solution is too ugly for me. And it is even more complex than implementing CURSOR